# KendoUI Toolbar splitButton automatically highlights the first option in the dropdownlist. How to make all options to looks the same

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, telerik, split-button

KendoUI Toolbar splitButton automatically highlights(partially in the link provided and in my case, completely) the first option in the dropdownlist. 
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/toolbar/index

In this url, if we observe, the Insert option has "Insert Above" set to blue instead of black. Similarly for Paragraph. 
How can I make all of them look the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize css like that

```
<style>
    .k-button.k-state-focused, .k-button:focus {
      border: 0px !important; 
      background-color: #ffffff !important;
    }

    .k-button.k-state-focused, .k-button:hover {
      background-color: #f4f4f4 !important;
    }

    .k-list-optionlabel.k-state-selected.k-state-focused{
      background-color: #ffffff !important;
      border: 0px !important; 
    }
    .k-list-optionlabel.k-state-selected.k-state-focused:hover{
      background-color: #f4f4f4 !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am new to web programming. I did change the css file, however, only the main menu button is changed but not the options. I added like this...

Comment: Html: <div id="rpt-toolbarOptions" style="float: right; border: none;" kendo-toolbar k-options="toolbarOptions"></div>      css file: #rpt-toolbarOptions .k-button.k-state-focused, #rpt-toolbarOptions .k-button:focus {
  border: 0px;
  background-color: #9FC5F8;
}
#rpt-toolbarOptions .k-button.k-state-focused, #rpt-toolbarOptions .k-button:hover {
  background-color: #c1d4d1;
} and other options in the similar way

Comment: In angular, I added the buttons. $scope.toolbarOptions = {items: [
                {
                    type: "splitButton",
                    text: "New Report",
                    menuButtons: [
                        { text: "Insert"},
                        { text: "Create"},
                        { text: "Download " }
                    ],
                    selected: "false"
                } ]

Comment: can try to demo your case here http://dojo.telerik.com/UgixE and update the link?